# Remove file from git repository definitively

Tags: git

I pushed a file which contains some password on my git repository.
How can I remove it? Because I removed it in the latest version (git rm) but it's still accessible using previous commits.

There is a solution about that?

Thanks.

Comment: How many commits happened after the problematic one?

Comment: I think you can't, you can `reset` the commit but then your history will be messed up.

Comment: About one hundred commits after the problematic one. In fact, the repo was private at start and I made it public yersteday, today I remembered that one file contains some passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub has a [good article](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) about that. It's not GitHub specific, and will work with any git repository.

Comment: I'm trying it, take a loooong time, I hope I will not destroy my repo ^^

Comment: git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.txt"  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all